# Setting up multiple I2C buses using dtoverlay

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-3b+, i2c, config.txt

I am trying to set up multiple I2C interfaces on my pi.

I have added the following lines to my /boot/config.txt and rebooted:

`dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=4,i2c_gpio_delay_us=1,i2c_gpio_sda=29,i2c_gpio_scl=31`

`dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=3,i2c_gpio_delay_us=1,i2c_gpio_sda=35,i2c_gpio_scl=37`

I have pull up resistors, and one i2c device wired to each of those pairs of pins with corresponding SDA/SCL. However, running `i2cdetect -l` shows this:

`i2c-3   i2c           i2c@3                                           I2CAdapter`

Have I done something wrong? I have i2c-dev enabled via modprobe, and I have also enabled the I2C interface via raspi-config. Is there something else I need to do?

EDIT: Note, the i2c-3 bus shows up empty.

Comment: Are you using a compute module?  Standard Pis only have GPIO 0-27.

Comment: @joan I don't think so, but pinout.xyz has the GPIO pins going 1-40

Comment: @joan According to the Rpi website, the 3B+ comes standard with a 40 pin gpio header. Is there something special I have to do to use dtoverlay with those extra pins?

Comment: Looks like you're using the physical pin numbers. You need to use the BCM numbers as they are listed on the pinout website

Comment: @Dirk THAT WORKED! If you would like to add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using the physical pin numbers.

All RPF documentation, settings and software (such as dtoverlay, gpiozero, etc) work with the BCM numbers.
You can find these at [pinout](https://pinout.xyz/) and elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

***Question***

> How to set up multiple I2C buses on Rpi3B+ and Rpi4B?

---

***Answer***

I often read forum discussions on setting I2C buses. I tried all for my Rpi3B+'s but all failed, perhaps my drivers or Rpi stretch was to updated.  The guys saying it is OK never specified their os version or driver used.

> I tried again for Rpi4B and found that I could use at least 2 buses very
> stable, 3 buses more or less stable, depending on length of connecting wires.

i2cdetect shows 5 busses, but only first 4 working, but not stable.

To do - I read that a new buster sep26 version is more stable (2019 june versions were bad.)

---

This is a summary of the config proved working. More details in Appendix A below

> dtoverlay=i2c1,pins_2_3  (board pins 3, 5)
>
> dtoverlay=i2c3,pins_4_5  (board pins 7, 29)
>
> dtoverlay=i2c4,pins_6_7  (board pins 31, 26)
>
> dtoverlay=i2c5,pins_12_13 (board pins 32, 33)
>
> dtoverlay=i2c6,pins_22_23 (board pins 15, 16)
>
> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /dev/i2c*
>
> /dev/i2c-1  /dev/i2c-3  /dev/i2c-4  /dev/i2c-5  /dev/i2c-6

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - Rpi4V raspbian 10 buster Python 3.7.3  Multiple I2C Channel Testing Notes*

```
# fi2c62.py  tlfong01 2019aug28hkt1433

from time          import sleep
import             smbus
import             fprint53    as fprint
import             ftime53     as ftime

# I2c Bus Setup Notes
# pi@raspberrypi:~ $ date Wed 28 Aug 2019 03:26:24 PM HKT
# pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
# Linux raspberrypi 4.19.58-v7l+ #1245 SMP Fri Jul 12 17:31:45 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
# pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo nano /boot/config.txt
# dtoverlay=i2c1,pins_2_3  (board pins 3, 5)
# dtoverlay=i2c3,pins_4_5  (board pins 7, 29)
# dtoverlay=i2c4,pins_6_7  (board pins 31, 26)
# dtoverlay=i2c5,pins_12_13 (board pins 32, 33)
# dtoverlay=i2c6,pins_22_23 (board pins 15, 16)
# pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /dev/i2c*
# /dev/i2c-1  /dev/i2c-3  /dev/i2c-4  /dev/i2c-5  /dev/i2c-6

# ********************************************************************************
# ********************************************************************************

# *** I2c Bus Config ***

i2cBus1 = smbus.SMBus(1) 
i2cBus3 = smbus.SMBus(3)
i2cBus4 = smbus.SMBus(4)
i2cBus5 = smbus.SMBus(5)

i2cBusDict = {'I2cBus1': i2cBus1,
              'I2cBus3': i2cBus3,
              'I2cBus4': i2cBus4,
              'I2cBus5': i2cBus5,
             }

# *** Pca9685 I2c Slave Device Congif ***

pca9685DevAddrDict = {
                'Dev0': 0x40,
                'Dev1': 0x41,
                'Dev2': 0x42,
                'Dev3': 0x43,
                'Dev4': 0x44,
                'Dev5': 0x45,
                'Dev6': 0x46,
                'Dev7': 0x47,
              }

pca9685RegAddrDict = { 'Mode1': 0x00,
                       'Mode2': 0x01,
                     }

pca9685DataByteDict = {
                       'Mode1Reset': 0x11,
    
    }

# ********************************************************************************
# ********************************************************************************

# *** Read Write Print Device/Register Functions ***

def writeDevTwoBytes(i2cBus, devAddr, writeByte1, writeByte2):
    i2cBus.write_byte_data(devAddr, writeByte1, writeByte2)
    return

def writeRegOneByte(i2cBus, devAddrDict, devName, regAddrDict, regName, writeByte):
    devAddr = devAddrDict[devName]
    regAddr = regAddrDict[regName]
    writeDevTwoBytes(i2cBus, devAddr, regAddr, writeByte)
    return

def readDevOneByte(i2cBus, devAddr, readByteAddr):
    readByte = i2cBus.read_byte_data(devAddr, readByteAddr)
    return readByte

def readRegOneByte(i2cBus, devAddrDict, devName, regAddrDict, regName):
    devAddr = devAddrDict[devName]
    regAddr = regAddrDict[regName]
    readByte = i2cBus.read_byte_data(devAddr, regAddr)
    return readByte

def printRegOneByte(i2cBus, devAddrDict, devName, regAddrDict, regName):
    readByte = readRegOneByte(i2cBusName, devAddrDict, devName, regAddrDict, regName)
    print(printTitle, hex(readByte))
    return
    
# *** Main Test Function ***

def testWriteReadPca9685Bus1Dev0RegMode1():     
    fprint.printBeginExecFunction()

    i2cBusName = 'I2cBus1'
    devName    = 'Dev0'
    regName    = 'Mode1'
   
    #i2cBus      = fi2c.i2cBusDict[i2cBusName]
    i2cBus      = i2cBusDict[i2cBusName]
    devAddrDict = pca9685DevAddrDict
    regAddrDict = pca9685RegAddrDict  
 
    writeByte = 0x77
    
    writeRegOneByte(i2cBus, devAddrDict, devName, regAddrDict, regName, writeByte)
    readByte = readRegOneByte(i2cBus, devAddrDict, devName, regAddrDict, regName) 
    
    if readByte == writeByte:
        resultsString = 'Good'
    else:
        resultsString = 'Bad'

    devAddr = devAddrDict[devName]
     
    fprint.printTitleOneByteNum('PCA9685 I2C Address',             fprint.indentFormat640, devAddr)
    fprint.printTitleOneByteNum('PCA9685 MODE1 Register Written',  fprint.indentFormat640, writeByte) 
    fprint.printTitleOneByteNum('PCA9685 MODE1 Register Read',     fprint.indentFormat640, readByte)    
    fprint.printTitleString('Write/Read Results',                  fprint.indentFormat640, resultsString)
 
    fprint.printEndExecFunction()
    return

def testPingPca9685Bus1Dev0RegMode1():     
    fprint.printBeginExecFunction()
    
    i2cBusName = 'I2cBus1'
    devName    = 'Dev0'
    regName    = 'Mode1'
   
    #i2cBus      = fi2c.i2cBusDict[i2cBusName]
    i2cBus      = i2cBusDict[i2cBusName]
    devAddrDict = pca9685DevAddrDict
    regAddrDict = pca9685RegAddrDict
    
    devAddr = devAddrDict[devName]
    
    readByte = readRegOneByte(i2cBus, devAddrDict, devName, regAddrDict, regName)    

    compareByte = pca9685DataByteDict['Mode1Reset'] 
    
    if readByte == compareByte:
        resultsString = 'Good'
    else:
        resultsString = 'Bad'
        
    fprint.printTitleString('PCA9685 I2C Address',             fprint.indentFormat640, hex(devAddr))
    fprint.printTitleString('PCA9685 MODE1 Register Written',  fprint.indentFormat640, hex(compareByte)) 
    fprint.printTitleString('PCA9685 MODE1 Register Read',     fprint.indentFormat640, hex(readByte))    
    fprint.printTitleString('Ping Results',                    fprint.indentFormat640, resultsString)
 
    fprint.printEndExecFunction()
    return
   
# ********************************************************************************
# ********************************************************************************

# *** Main Tests ***

def mainTests():
    #ftime.testPrintDateTime()
    testPingPca9685Bus1Dev0RegMode1()
    testWriteReadPca9685Bus1Dev0RegMode1()
    return
    
# ********************************************************************************
# ********************************************************************************

# *** Init/Main Functions ***

# *** Init Function ***

def init():
    pass
    return

#*** Main Function ***

def main():
    init()
    mainTests()    
    return

# ********************************************************************************
# ********************************************************************************

# *** Main ***

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# *** End of Program ***

# ********************************************************************************
# ********************************************************************************
```

---

*End of answer*