# How to get accurate SPO2 readings from MAX30100

Tags: pi-4, python-3

As you can read from the title, I'm not getting accurate SPO2 readings in the output. I should be getting values of 100 and below since it is in percentage: but I keep getting values over 100 (like 134 etc.) Does anyone know how to calibrate the accuracy of the sensor? Or if it's actually possible in the first place HAHA

I'm using Raspberry Pi 4, connected the MAX30100 VIN to 3.3V, GND to GND, SDA to SDA, SCL to SCL

This is the code that I used to test out the sensor, any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import time
import max30100

mx30 = max30100.MAX30100()
mx30.enable_spo2()

while 1:
    mx30.read_sensor()
    mx30.ir, mx30.red

    hb = int(mx30.ir / 100)
    spo2 = int(mx30.red / 100)

    if mx30.ir != mx30.buffer_ir :
        print("Pulse:",hb);
    if mx30.red != mx30.buffer_red:
        print("SPO2:",spo2);

    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: this might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111955/how-can-rpi-read-the-max30100-max30102-oximeter/112088#112088